# javafx buttons not working on TranslaeTransition

Tags: javafx-8

The circle should go back and forth but the start button is not starting it for some reason? When I ran the example file it worked and it looks exactly like mine so not sure why Mine isnt starting. Does anybody know why? Thanks

```
package projavafx.metronometransition.ui;


import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MetronomeTransitionMain extends Application{

Button startButton;
Button pauseButton;
Button resumeButton;
Button stopButton;
Circle circle;

public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args);}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    circle = new Circle(100, 50, 4, Color.BLUE);
    TranslateTransition anim = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(1000.0), circle);
    anim.setFromX(0);
    anim.setToX(200);
    anim.setAutoReverse(true);
    anim.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    anim.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    startButton = new Button("start");
    startButton.setOnAction(e -> anim.playFromStart());
    pauseButton = new Button("pause");
    startButton.setOnAction(e -> anim.pause());
    resumeButton = new Button("resume");
    resumeButton.setOnAction(e -> anim.play());
    stopButton = new Button("stop");
    stopButton.setOnAction(e -> anim.stop());
    HBox commands = new HBox(10, startButton,
            pauseButton,
            resumeButton,
            stopButton);
    commands.setLayoutX(60);
    commands.setLayoutY(420);
    Group group = new Group(circle, commands);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 500);

    startButton.disableProperty().bind(anim.statusProperty()
            .isNotEqualTo(Animation.Status.STOPPED));
    pauseButton.disableProperty().bind(anim.statusProperty()
            .isNotEqualTo(Animation.Status.RUNNING));
    resumeButton.disableProperty().bind(anim.statusProperty()
            .isNotEqualTo(Animation.Status.PAUSED));
    stopButton.disableProperty().bind(anim.statusProperty()
            .isEqualTo(Animation.Status.STOPPED));

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Metronome using TranslateTransition");
    stage.show();
}
```

}

Comment: I found the error , my apologies

Comment: this should be
    pauseButton = new Button("pause");
    pauseButton.setOnAction(e -> anim.pause());